# Pass dataTable in JSON format (ajax), to a MVC Controller (JAVA)

Tags: java, ajax, spring, model-view-controller

I'm new at AJAX , and i'm strugglying to pass an object to a controller.

i tried this :

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#mov').click(function(){
            var dni = parseInt($('#dni').val());
            
            var table = $('#tablaSeleccionados').tableToJSON();
            
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',                
                url:'${pageContext.request.contextPath}/saveMovBienes',
                data:  {dni:dni,table:table},
                dataType: "json"                
            })
        })
    })
```

Controller

```
@PostMapping("/saveMovBienes")
    public String saveMovBienes(@RequestParam(name="dni", required=false) Integer dni,
                                @RequestParam(name="table", required=false) String listado) {
        
        
        System.out.println("PER_ID= "+dni);
        System.out.println("LIST= "+ listado);
        
        return "";
    }
```

Tried changing the format of "listado" to List , Json, String, and nothing ...

If i add "toString()" to my var table, i see the elements in the controller, but like this: 'object [Object]', 'object [Object]'

Any guidence will be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to send your data as JSON in the body of the request, since you are creating a `POST` request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ...,
    data: JSON.stringify({ dni: dni, table: table }),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
})
```

On the backend you can hava a `@RestController` which will receive the data in a data transfer object (DTO) annotated with `@RequestBody`.

First, you have to create a DTO for the request body:

```
public class MyRequest {
   private String dni;
   private String table;

   // Getters and setters

}
```

Now, you cam create the rest controller:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @PostMapping("/saveMovBienes")
    public String saveMovBienes(@RequestBody MyRequest request) {
        System.out.println("PER_ID= " + request.getDni());
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Sir! Tryed your code but the output is the name of the parameter --> output: "dni" , "table" .  Apparently the ajax is not passing the values to the object MyRequest, or its passing something wrong.

Comment: My mistake, you should remove the `quotes` around `dni` and `table`. Updated answer.

Comment: Excelent, its working. Thanks a lot!